# How is it possible to change an img src using 'srcset' using JS, based on which onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, srcset

I'm trying to make a simple product page for t-shirts. The user can press different colored buttons, which should activate a function to see which ID is being clicked. Then based on the ID, the img src is changed to represent the current image/color t-shirt.

I want to use the 'srcset' attribute in JS.

Using IF statements, I've been able to change the color of the t-shirt onclick - but no mater which option is clicked only the last color in the array is presented.

The issue is that it only changes the t-shirt color to one color, seeming to ignore the 'else if'.

```js
var tShirtObj = {
    tShirt: document.getElementById('t-shirt'),
    green: document.getElementById('green'),
    blue: document.getElementById('blue'),
    gray: document.getElementById('gray'),
    black: document.getElementById('black'),
    yellow: document.getElementById('yellow')
};


// Function to check which ID's onclick is pressed to change the color.
function colorChange() {
    if (tShirtObj.green.onclick) {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035500.jpg" // green
    } else if (tShirtObj.blue.onclick) {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035400.jpg" // blue
    } else if (tShirtObj.gray.onclick) {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1118100.jpg" // gray
    } else if (tShirtObj.black.onclick) {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035200.jpg" // black
    } else if (tShirtObj.yellow.onclick) {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1012700.jpg" // yellow
    }
}
```

```css
.card {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn-red {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-gray {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-green {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(117, 184, 117);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-blue {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-yellow {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-black {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Animate.CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Animate CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Custom Javascript -->
  <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
  <title>JS SECTION</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center ">
    <h1>JAVASCRIPT CHANGE PRODUCT COLOR</h1>

    <h1 class="display-4">T-shirt</h1>

    <div class="card mt-5" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1118100.jpg"
        class="card-img-top pt-3" alt=T-shirt id="t-shirt">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">T shirt, premium</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This premium T-shirt is made from the finest cotton in the world! Many sizes and colors!
        </p>
        <p><span>$</span>9.99,-</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success float-left mt-3">PURCHASE!</a>
        
        <div class="floating float-right">
          <button class="btn-gray" onclick="colorChange()" id="gray"></button>
          <button class="btn-red" onclick="colorChange()" id="red"></button>
          <button class="btn-yellow" onclick="colorChange()" id="yellow"></button>
          <div></div>
          <button class="btn-blue" onclick="colorChange()" id="blue"></button>
          <button class="btn-black" onclick="colorChange()" id="black"></button>
          <button class="btn-green" onclick="colorChange()" id="green"></button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/KeyanAb/pen/jgGKPN)

What am I doing wrong?

If there's an easier way to do this using srcset/attribute manipulation in JS please don't hesitate to let me know. Just kindly tell me how your code works if it isn't beginner friendly.

Comment: That's not what srcset is for, it's for having the browser automatically change the image it's displaying based on (implicit or explicit) media queries. What you're doing is really just "replacing the image url", so just do that: change `.src` and don't bother with `srcset`. Also, I can highly recommend using classes instead of ids: having unique elements on a page called `green` or `blue` is really weird. Having an `<img id="t-shirt-image"?` makes a lot of sense, and then make your buttons swap the `src` attribute for that single image.

Comment: `if (tShirtObj.green.onclick)` does not do what you think. Go find a tutorial for `onclick`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass a parameter in your code, that will do the work.

I've edited your code and just set a parameter on your onChange function.

```js
var tShirtObj = {
    tShirt: document.getElementById('t-shirt'),
    green: document.getElementById('green'),
    blue: document.getElementById('blue'),
    gray: document.getElementById('gray'),
    black: document.getElementById('black'),
    yellow: document.getElementById('yellow')
};


// Function to check which ID's onclick is pressed to change the color.
function colorChange(a) {
    if (a=='green') {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035500.jpg" // green
    } else if (a=='blue') {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035400.jpg" // blue
    } else if (a=='gray') {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1118100.jpg" // gray
    } else if (a=='black') {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035200.jpg" // black
    } else if (a=='yellow') {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1012700.jpg" // yellow
    }
}
```

```css
.card {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn-red {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-gray {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-green {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(117, 184, 117);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-blue {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-yellow {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-black {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Animate.CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Animate CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Custom Javascript -->
  <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
  <title>JS SECTION</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center ">
    <h1>JAVASCRIPT CHANGE PRODUCT COLOR</h1>

    <h1 class="display-4">T-shirt</h1>

    <div class="card mt-5" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1118100.jpg"
        class="card-img-top pt-3" alt=T-shirt id="t-shirt">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">T shirt, premium</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This premium T-shirt is made from the finest cotton in the world! Many sizes and colors!
        </p>
        <p><span>$</span>9.99,-</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success float-left mt-3">PURCHASE!</a>
        
        <div class="floating float-right">
          <button class="btn-gray" onclick="colorChange('gray')" id="gray"></button>
          <button class="btn-red" onclick="colorChange('gray')" id="red"></button>
          <button class="btn-yellow" onclick="colorChange('yellow')" id="yellow"></button>
          <div></div>
          <button class="btn-blue" onclick="colorChange('blue')" id="blue"></button>
          <button class="btn-black" onclick="colorChange('black')" id="black"></button>
          <button class="btn-green" onclick="colorChange('green')" id="green"></button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to review the way you perform the test.

The line of code `if (tShirtObj.green.onclick) {` is actually checking if you have a onclick event associated.

You can find here a simplified exemple of the condition with a variable :

```
let f = function() { alert('I am doing something'); }

if (f)
    alert('I will be executed');
```

If you want more information on [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).

The best solution for your problem is to use the event objects. (e in this exemple)

```
function colorChange(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'green') {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035500.jpg" // green
    } else if (e.target.id == 'blue') {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035400.jpg" // blue
    } else if (e.target.id == 'gray') {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1118100.jpg" // gray
    } else if (e.target.id == 'black') {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035200.jpg" // black
    } else if (e.target.id == 'yellow') {
        tShirtObj.tShirt.srcset = "https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1012700.jpg" // yellow
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it simpler
JS:

```
let tShirt = document.getElementById('t-shirt');
let srcMap = new Map([
    ['green', 'https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035500.jpg'],
    ['blue', 'https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035400.jpg'],
    ['gray', 'https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1118100.jpg'],
    ['black', 'https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035200.jpg'],
    ['yellow', 'https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1012700.jpg'],
]);

function colorChange(btn) {
    let src = srcMap.get(btn.id);
    tShirt.srcset = src;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="floating float-right">
    <button class="btn-gray" onclick="colorChange(this)" id="gray"></button>
    <button class="btn-red" onclick="colorChange(this)" id="red"></button>
    <button class="btn-yellow" onclick="colorChange(this)" id="yellow"></button>
    <div></div>
    <button class="btn-blue" onclick="colorChange(this)" id="blue"></button>
    <button class="btn-black" onclick="colorChange(this)" id="black"></button>
    <button class="btn-green" onclick="colorChange(this)" id="green"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

srcset is not for setting src with javascript. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_srcset.asp check this for more information.
But for what you are trying to do you. maintain separate functions to do separate things.

```
<!--buttons -->
<button class="btn-tshirt" data-myattribute="blue">blue</button>
<button class="btn-tshirt" data-myattribute="black">black</button>
<button class="btn-tshirt" data-myattribute="gray">gray</button>
<!-- the image -->
<img id="imageToChange" src="https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products- 
 images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035500.jpg" height="100" width="100">
```

then comes javascript

```
//get all buttons
  var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-tshirt");
 /*we maintain all images be careful here because in the key value pair here
  * the key should be used as a attribute for the image
  */
  const images ={
      blue:"https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035400.jpg",
      black:"https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee-m__LC1035200.jpg",
      gray:"https://www.salomon.com/sites/default/files/products-images/900x900/xa-tee- m__LC1118100.jpg"
             } 
   //add event listener to all the buttons
   Array.from(classname).forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
    }); 
  // the below function is called when the button is clicked
  function myFunction() {
   var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
   changeSrc(images[attribute])
    }
  //change the image src here
  function changeSrc(url) {
      let image=  document.getElementById("imageToChange")
       image.src=url
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/56q4ta3e/1/